# freemarker + spring configuration and simplest example

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

Despite there are a lot of discussion around freemarker + spring but it is hard to find neat working example to copy and run.
Could you please provide simplest working configuration of freemarker in spring xml context and java code snippet to load template from resource file and process it.

Comment: This example is using java-based config and is still using a web project, but this is what I reference: https://github.com/edendramis/freemarker-example

Comment: Official docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view-freemarker

Answer (score 25, accepted):

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

applicationContext.xml

```xml
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurationFactory" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/META-INF/freemarker"/>
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

AlertMailComposer.java

```java
import static org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString;

@Component
public class AlertMailComposer implements Processor {
    
    public static final String TEMPLATE = "AlertMail.ftl";
    
    @Autowired
    private Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;
    
    protected String composeHtml(Alert alert) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        return processTemplateIntoString(freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate(TEMPLATE), ImmutableMap.of(
                "alertType", alert.getAlertType(),
                "message", alert.getMessage(),
                "nodeName", alert.getEvent().getNodeName(),
                "event", toJson(alert.getEvent(), true)
        ));
    }
...
```

AlertMail.ftl

```html
<html>
<body style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10">
    <b>${alertType}: </b>${message}<br>
    <b>on: </b>${nodeName}<br>
    <p/>
    <pre style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10;color:grey">
${event}
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

---

`Configuration` class has some interesting properties, like `ClassForTemplateLoading` to load resources relative to some class or using basePackagePath. Similar to `Class.getResource`.

```
@Autowired
private FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory freeMarkerConfigurationFactory;

@Bean
public freemarker.template.Configuration negativeRatesFreeMarkerConfiguration() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    freemarker.template.Configuration configuration = freeMarkerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration();
    configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(getClass(), "/" + getClass().getPackage().getName().replace('.', '/'));
    return configuration;
}

...

@Resource(name = "negativeRatesFreeMarkerConfiguration")
private Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;

...

freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("/service/emailReport.ftl")
```

Answer (score 4):

In the spring context xml, declaring `FreemarkerConfigurationFactoryBean` is sufficient, i.e.

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfigFactory" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:templates/"/>
</bean>
```

No need to further specify `freemarker.template.Configuration` bean in the xml file if you use `@Autowired` annotation. It is created by the factory and injected by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Best working example. You can download source code [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-freemarker-ftl-example/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've already worked through this blog and it is good. But It is tightly bind to web project layout. What I'm looking for is 'load template from resource and substitute placehoders' as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Other than maven dependency in pom.xml to use it with java configuration in spring you can do -

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { MyRootContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { MyServletContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/test/*" };
    } 

}
```

and then `MyRootContextConfig` can have

```
@Bean(name = "myFreeMarkerConfigruation")
public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean getFreeMarkerConfiguration() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean bean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
    bean.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates/");
    return bean;
}
```